# Selenium html button not clicking

Tags: selenium

This is my HTML code

```
 <button type="button" class="button primary" id="submitID" aria-label="Verify and proceed to next step.">
        Verify
 </button>
```

This is my selenium code:

```
 WebElement verifyButton = driver.findElement(By.id("submitID"));
 verifyButton.click();
```

The button comes to focus but not clicking.

Comment: Is there any action attached to you button?

Comment: Do you have any additional details?  Based on what you're showing, it should work.  So the fact that it isn't means that something else is at play.  Without more context, we're even more in the dark than you.  What have you tried already?  Sharing your failed attempts and motivations will help us understand where you're coming from and how you can proceed to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this in case there are multiple elements with the same `id`:

```
WebElement verifyButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@id='submitID']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript executor . Please ref below code

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('submitID').click();");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of this thing here

- **Using ID**

  ```
  WebElement verifyBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("submitID"));
  verifyBtn.click();
  ```
- **Using class name**

  ```
  WebElement verifyBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("button primary"));
  verifyBtn.click()
  ```
- **Using xpath**

  ```
  WebElement verifyBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Verify and proceed to next step.' and @id='submitID']"));
  verifyBtn.click()
  ```
- **Using javascriptExecutor**

  ```
  WebElement verifyBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("submitID"));
  JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", verifyBtn );
  ```

Comment: Did you mean By.xpath("//button[@id = 'submitID']")?

Answer (score 0):

If **ID** is unique, you might wanna wait for some time and then click on it.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("submitID"))).click();
```

**OR** **cssSelector** :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[type='button'][id='submitID']"))).click();
```

**OR XPATH :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Verify']"))).click();
```

**OR XPATH :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@aria-label,'Verify and proceed to next step.')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the output of this? note - findElement**S**

```
driver.findElements(By.id("submitID")).size()
```

for sure there are many buttons with same id, which must not happen in valid html